# Combining same variables in array and adding the sum of their values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to a code to merge duplicate variables and summing their values together

```
 fruit = [
  ["yellow", 1],
  ["red", 1],
  ["orange", 3],
  ["yellow", 1],
  ["orange", 2]

]

//desired output
  combinedColours = [
  ["yellow", 2],
  ["red", 1],
  ["orange", 5]

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [
  ["yellow", 1],
  ["red", 1],
  ["orange", 3],
  ["yellow", 1],
  ["orange", 2]
];

const result = Object.entries(
  data.reduce((r, [k, v]) => (r[k] = ((r[k] || 0) + v), r), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```